# Opening pdf from other application

Tags: iphone

i am developing an iPad application. in this application i am downloading the pdf from web. is it possible to open this pdf from another readers like adobe. i am saving the pdf in my custom directory.

if so how can i code in my application to open the pdf from another application

Answer (score 2):

You can export your PDF to other application via the UIDocumentInteractionController.

Otherwise as @Björn Kaiser said, each application's storage is jailed and cannot be accessed by other application.

Answer (score 0):

No other App can access your App's directories.